# javascript code in apex page

Tags: apex, javascript, visualforce

I have a check in apex page with javascript code as below under script tags.

```
var proli ="{! $Profile.Name  }";
//alert(proli);
if(proli=='Abbott DM' || proli=='Field Profile' )
{
alert('{!$Profile.Name} not authorized to publish');
var isok =alert('{!$Profile.Name} not authorized to publish- Click OK to go back');
var a;
 a = setTimeout('window.location.href="/a4M?fcf=00BM0000000tpnc";',1);
}
```

I need the if clause above to check `proli!='Abbott DM'`. But it is not working. Can someone please let me know how to get that?

Comment: What you mean by **not working?** the value of `proli` depends on the time this snippet get executed

Comment: when I place '!=' it's unable to validate and loading my page without the alert. And Settimeout not working

Comment: does '!=' operator works here for 'if' clause?

Comment: Seems it's quote marks. Can you go inside with `alert(proli+'not authorized to publish');` ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not with the `if` condition but the way you pass values into the `alert` function. To evaluate `{!$Profile.Name}` it should be inside quote marks. So either you can use your `proli` variable to handle this

```
alert(proli + ' not authorized to publish');
```

Or you have to manage quote marks as below.

```
alert("'{!$Profile.Name}' not authorized to publish");
```

Apply this for the below lines of your snippet as well.

Comment: But it works fine for '==' condition fails for '!=' only

Comment: When it's `!=`, it turns condition to `false` so the `if` block doesn't get hit isn't it? Try putting some `alert()` in the `else` block as well or check for any script errors with any inspect tool like firebug